Checking a Cell value of Sheet B and apply formatting to a Range in Sheet A in loop
Got stuck with Excel VBA while creating loop with conditional formatting.
I have to search the value of Sheet B Cell G2 and apply conditional formatting to Sheet A Range from A2 to D2.
Post that it will check Sheet B Cell A3 and again based on the value it will apply conditional formatting to Sheet A Range from A3 to D3.
I am using a script but not able to proceed further as confused with looping two places
Sub formatting()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition

  Set rng = Range("A2", "D2")

   rng.FormatConditions.Delete
   
   Sheets("B").Select

    Range("G2").Select

   Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=False")
   Set condition2 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=0")

    With condition1
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End With


     With condition2
     With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End With

End Sub 

Not able to loop between Cell value in Sheet B and apply this condition to Range A:D in Sheet A

A bit late, but this could get you moving. I don't understand your issue completely and this code is untested, but it tries to do what you describe.
Sub Formatting2()
    
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range
Dim ShtA As Worksheet, ShtB As Worksheet
Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition

Set ShtA = Worksheets("A")
Set ShtB = Worksheets("B")

'Step 1: remove conditial formats from A2:D10 on Sheet A.
Set RngA = ShtA.Range("A2:D10")
RngA.FormatConditions.Delete

If ShtB.Range("G2").Value = 16 Then
    'I have to search the value of Sheet B Cell G2 and apply conditional formatting to Sheet A Range from A2 to D2.
    'This IF checks if Sheet B, cell G2 has a certain value (16 in this example) and then applies conditional formatting
    Set RngA = ShtA.Range("A2:D2")
    Set condition1 = RngA.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=False")
    Set condition2 = RngA.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=0")
    With condition1
        With Selection.Font
            .Color = -16776961
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
    With condition2
        With Selection.Font
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End If

'Post that it will check Sheet B Cell A3 and again based on the value it will apply conditional formatting to Sheet A Range from A3 to D3.
'I am using a script but not able to proceed further as confused with looping two places

End Sub

